WorkManager custom WorkerFactory with context
how to do this if Context is only available in onCreate so workManagerConfiguration can't be initialised?
class MyApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    lateinit var appContainer: AppContainer

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContainer = AppContainer(this)
    }

    override val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration = Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
        .setWorkerFactory(MyWorkerFactory(appContainer))
        .build()
}

class MyWorkerFactory(
    private val appContainer: AppContainer
) : WorkerFactory() {
    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker? {...}
}


You can call AppContainer(this) in any method in your application. What makes you think you can only call it in onCreate?

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference if i do it outside of onCreate. but in this case i guess i can just do (appContext as MyApplication).appContainer in MyWorkerFactory
